# unable to redeploy snapshot to nexus in play framework

Tags: frameworks, playframework, nexus, playframework-2.2

I'm using play 2.2 framework, I'm developing the module and defined it as snapshot.
I have published the snapshot to nexus but when I try to deploy the same without changing version or appname redeploy fails with below error:

> [info] Done packaging.
>   java.io.IOException: Access to URL http://mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mymodule/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mymodule-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom was refused by the server: Forbidden at org.apache.ivy.util.url.AbstractURLHandler.validatePutStatusCode(AbstractURLHandler.java:79
>   at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:231)
>   at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
>   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
>   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
>   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.put(RepositoryResolver.java:234)
>   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)

I know the reason for this failure, Nexus is denying the deploy due to the fact that the previous snapshot is also exactly same w/o timestamp.
Question is how to attach timestamp in Build.scala or any configuration in play framework that enable to redeploy of snapshots multiple times to Nexus. This is obviously is not a problem in maven project, but somehow evident in play framework projects.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Aravind

Answer (score 0):

Use the aether deploy instead of the sbt/ivy publish. This should create the metadata on the server correctly.

https://github.com/arktekk/sbt-aether-deploy